# Why my code does outputs ? (Probable logic issue)

Tags: python, string

Following problem is a problem from cs50 pset6. The goal here is to search for a `.txt file` that represent a `DNA thread` and check how many times a specific string occurs consecutively. If number of cons. string matches with an individual for each DNA example, print individuals name.

I am still a newbie with python, I wrote what I meant by the lines I hope all is right. Any help is appreciated. (At the moment code does not give any outputs)

python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/2.txt (commend line arguments,1st is the `csv` and 2nd is `txt` file)

CSV files :

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5

name,AGATC,TTTTTTCT,AATG,TCTAG,GATA,TATC,GAAA,TCTG
Albus,15,49,38,5,14,44,14,12
Cedric,31,21,41,28,30,9,36,44
Draco,9,13,8,26,15,25,41,39
Fred,37,40,10,6,5,10,28,8
Ginny,37,47,10,23,5,48,28,23
Hagrid,25,38,45,49,39,18,42,30
Harry,46,49,48,29,15,5,28,40
Hermione,43,31,18,25,26,47,31,36
James,46,41,38,29,15,5,48,22
Kingsley,7,11,18,33,39,31,23,14
Lavender,22,33,43,12,26,18,47,41
Lily,42,47,48,18,35,46,48,50
Lucius,9,13,33,26,45,11,36,39
Luna,18,23,35,13,11,19,14,24
Minerva,17,49,18,7,6,18,17,30
Neville,14,44,28,27,19,7,25,20
Petunia,29,29,40,31,45,20,40,35
Remus,6,18,5,42,39,28,44,22
Ron,37,47,13,25,17,6,13,35
Severus,29,27,32,41,6,27,8,34
Sirius,31,11,28,26,35,19,33,6
Vernon,26,45,34,50,44,30,32,28
Zacharias,29,50,18,23,38,24,22,9
```

.txt file example :

```
TGGTTTAGGGCCTATAATTGCAGGACCACTGGCCCTTGTCGAGGTGTACAGGTAGGGAGCTAAGTTCGAAACGCCCCTTGGTCGGGATTACCGCCATTCTAGTAGTCTAACCCCGAACGCGCTCAGGCTTTGAGTTCGCGCAGCATTAAGAAGTCCATGCCGGCACCGAATGTCCCGACGACAGGCAACCAGCACGGATACCCGCCTTGAAGGCGCAATCAGTAGGTCGAGTTACAGAGGCTCCCCCCGAGCTTGTGCTTCCATTGAGTAGGGGCTATAGATATGTAGCACTCAGGTTTAGTAGCGCCCTTTTAACAGCGAGAGCCCGCCTGGTCAGAACCGAACGGCTGATACGCGAGCTGATGGCTAGAGGATGAACACGGTCCTTCTCTTCGCTTCGATCCGGGGTAGTTTTGTAGCGAAGGATAACGCTCTGTGGATTCTCCGAGAATAATCATCAGTACGGTGTGCGTACCCTCTCTTTGATCCACGCCTGGGGCTGGACATAGTCAGGCGCATTTCATCTACTTAACCCCGGTAAGGGCCACGGGCGCGACATCTCCTTACCAGGGTTGTCTTATGCTCGCTTTTCCCAGATGATAAGCATCTCGTTGTAATGAACAGGTACCTAAGAAAACTGAGTTTCGACGACCCGTCGGCTCGTGTTCTTATCTATTGATCTAACCGAGGTGAAGCTCGCCAAAAATTTCGTAATGTAAGAGAGAAATTGAAGGGGTGAATTTTGCACTCTCGTGCATACGTCTTGCTACAATAGCAAGAGCTGTATGCGTGCGACCACTTCACTACCTCTATAGCATGCGATCTCGCAGCCCGGATTGTCGCCTCCTTTGGGCCGCAAAAACGGTATACGGACACACTGCATCTGTGAGCACGCACCAACTCGATGCGCGTAATAGGCATCTGCTCCACCCAGGGGGCAAGGGCACCTGAGGACGATCTGTTCCGAACAGTATATTTGAGCCAATGTTCTATTAGTGAAGGCAAGGTGAGGGCAACTCACACTGGTACCTCGAGGAGTAATCCGATCCATCTAAACTGGCATGCCCGTTCGAGCTCGGGGGGTTCTTGAATTTAGCTGCGTGTACCTCAGGTCTCCTGAAGGTGACACCAAAGTACAAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGGTAATATCTGACGTGAATTGCTTACCGCTAGTGAGCGATTTAGGTCACGTCCTCTGAAGATGTACCGTGATCATCGATGAAATGGCTCTGCAGAGCGTTGCTCTTAACTTAGTGGGAGTGTTCCTTTGCAGTCTGATGAAGTCGCTGCATGTTAACTTTGCACTAAGGGCGTTTCCGAACCCTATAGTCATCCTTATTGATTCGCCCTGTCTTACCCAGGATACACTACCGTTCGAGGCTCTTAACGTACCAACGCATGCAGTCAGAAGATGATTCACCATCCAAGCAAATCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTCTGTGGCTTTAAAGCACCGAATGTAGTTGGCCATCGGTCTCGGTCACCAATAAGACGGCCTCGTGGGTCACTCGGTCGATGATCTAGGGTCGGGTGCATAGTGTTTCAGGTCGGCGCTCAGGGTTCTTGTCAGGGAAATCTACGGGTGAGTTGGAAAGCGCCGCCAGCGAGATGCCTGTAGGCGATTAGTGTAGAGAGAGCAACATCGGAAAATTGTCCGTGGGGCGCTACGTAAGTGTTCCCAGTATTCTCGTCCAGAGTAAGTCATGCATACCAGTATCAGGCGTCTGTGTGTTACGTTGCAGTGTATCCCGGTAGCGGGAAGCGTATAGAGCGTAACAGACCTGTCCTACAGCACGCAGGATGTCGACCCTTTCTCAGGCACGATACTTCGTGTAACAGCAGTTCCGGTGTCATCTGTAACTGTTCTGTGTTCCATAGTGAAGATATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCGGGCGACCCTGGCAATCAGGCGCCTGCTTATATGACAATTTGTCGCAATACGGGTCGCAGATGTATTGTCCGCATGAGTTTACGGTATCCGGAACTGTCACCGCCGATCCAATATGATCGCAAATCGGGGTGACACAATGGACCGCCGTAGATAAACCCTGCGATGCTGCAATAAGGATATGATATCGCGCGCGGGCCGTAAAACCGATCTTGGAAGGCGGGAAGTCTCCGGGAAAAACTCTCTGATAAAGCCTATTACAAGAAGAGCTCGAAGGCAAGATGGGCATGCCCCGTCGACCACACGGGCAAGCTCTGAGAATCGATGTGGTCGCTTAACCAACCCATACGGAGTGAACGAGACCACGCGGGCGGTTCTTGGTACGCATGATTCCTATTGGTTCTGCCGGGCGTGTGCAGGATTGTTCACTCCCCACCCTGTCGCTCACGAACGCGCTGGTTGCTTAAACCGACCGGAAATTCTGTAGCCGCCCCGTAAGTTTAACGCTTTGAAATACTCCACATGTGCGTACCGGGTCTGATCGCTTACGTGGCGCCACTATGTTAGGAGCTCATAGATATCGATGAATCAAATGTCTTTCATCGCTCCTTAAACAACCTGACGTATTCGCAAAATTGCGCGTATTGAGAAGGGAAAGTTAAAGGAACGATAACAATGAGTCTGCTTTCACCGGCTGCATAACGGGATCGCGCGCTATGGGATTTCCTAACTATAATTCGTGTCGATACTCAGACGCGTTGTACAGGTAAGAAGTCGGCGGGACAGTATTTGAGAAGGGGCTCTGCGGCACCAACGCCGAGCTGTATCAGGGGGGTTAATGTGTAGCGGGCATATAACACAATACAGCCCGCGGCGCGTCGTGGTTACCGTAGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGAATGGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAAGAAACACCGGAGCTAGGATCCACGACTACCAGTGGGAAACTGTGAATTGTGCATGGTAATTAAAGGATGACTGGTCAACACCGGTCTCCACGGGCGTTAAACAACCTCGCTCCAGTCAATCTCTAGCGGTGGTTGTGGCAGCTTATTCCTGGAGGTAATACTCTTCCGGGCCCACTAAAAATGTAACGAAGTCGAGGTTGGGTCAGGGGATTGAGTGGGGGCGACTCACTGATTCCACCAGGAATTGTCGTCAATCGCGACGTACTTTGAGCCTTGTATCTTGGCGTTTCTTGTTGGTACGCGGCCGTGTTCGTGAATCACGACGTCGTTCATGATTCATCCGTCCAAGCCTAGACCTAGCGTAAAAACGGTGTCGATCTGTGCTCCAACCGATGGATGGTTTTTACACAAGTGAACTTCGAGGCTGTGGGACAAACAGCACAACTTGTTCACTGCTGACCGTGGTACTAAACCACGCTTGCTTTCAGCCCTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTTTTTTTCTCAGATGCGGATCAAGGGTTACTCGAGCCGTTCTGAGGTCCTAAAATTTTAGCCCTTGGTGTTAGCTTCGGTTTAAGAACGTAGGTGCGACGCGGGGGTCCTAGAGCTCCGCGATCTGCACTCCCCACCTGGCACCAAAACGAATCCTGCATAACGGCTCTCTGTGCATGGGGGATGGTCGCAACAACGAGCATAGCTGGCATCACTTCGTTTGCTGTGGATTGCTGTTTTATACAGAATACGGTGGTGATCATCAAAGGAAGCATAATCCACATCGGGCACCCCGGGCCATCGTGCGTTCCCTTATAGCCGGCTTGCATGTTGGGGGAGGAGTAAGGCCGGTAACGTCTCGCAGCACTGTCGCGTAACACAGGTACATCTTTATTTCCGGTGCTGTAGAAGTGGTTTTTCGAAGGCGTAACCCAGAACGACTGATATAATAGTCCACTATTCCCTGGTTTAAGACTTCTACAAAGTTTTACGCAAAGTTACATGCACACTCGGCGACGTAAATATTAGCCTTGCTAAATTGCCACGGATATTAATCCCGAGCCAACCTGTTCCCACTAGCGGTCTACGGTCATAGTCCTTTGTGTAGAGCGTCATTGCGGTTGGGGCCCGTCCGCGGAGGTTCCCCTTATGATCTAACCGCGGTGCAGGTTGACTGAATGCCATACACTATAGAGAAGACGTCTAAGTAGAAACGTTCTTTAAAAATCTTGAACTGACGGCCGAGTATTATCAAGAGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCATGCACAATAAGGTTAGAAGCAGCAAGCATGTATTCTTTGCATAGAGGCGGTAAAGCCGCCTTGCATACCCAGCAGCAGCCGCGAAGGCCTTACTCCAGAGGACAGAACTTCTCACACAGCGTCCGCATACACCGCGGACGTGACAAGGTTAGATAGCTCTAGTTTGCGGCAACCCTCGCATCAGGCCGACTCACCCGCGCTTGCTACCCGGAGGATGGGTCAAGGGATAAACATAGCACGTTAGTTAAGCCTAACGTCAGTTTTTAGAGTTTACATGCACGACTAAGTGCATCGAAATACACGCCGTTGACAGACCAACAGCGTGTCAACTGGGCCTTGAGAATTGTATCATAATAGCCAAATACGAGGCCAAGTAGTCCGACGAGAGGCACGTAGAGACCACTTTCCCTAAACGATCTGTCGCATTACCCTTTGACTCGCACCCTATGCCTTATGTTCCAAGCAGCACCGAAGTTAGATTTAAGGGCGTATCTATCGGTACCTCGGTTGGGCCGGTCCACAGCTCCAGCTGAATTAGTGCTCACCCCGCTTCGAGGTTGAGTAAGGGTCACTTTTAAAAATATGCTTAAGGGTGATTCACATGACAGTAATCGAATAGTGAGATATAAGTAGGTGCGCCCCGCGCACACATCAAAACTGTGCAGACTGAAACTGAATGCTGGAGGCTGAGGAAAATGAAGATCAGAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGTCTAGAGAAGAGTGAATGAATAGATCTGCCGCTGAATCCCCGCGTGAGGTTTTTGCGAC
```

Code:

```
from sys import argv
import csv
from itertools import groupby
#first csv cma 2nd txt
# fread from CSV file first thing in a row is name then the number of strs
# fread from dna seq and read it into a memory
#find how many times each str censequetivel
# if number of strs == with a persons print the person

checkstr = [] #global array that tells us what str to read
def readtxt(csvfile,seq):
    with open(f'{csvfile}','r') as p:#finding which str to read from header line of the csv
        header = csv.reader(p) # Header contains which strs to look for
        for row in header:
            checkstr = row[1:]
            break
    with open(f'{seq}','r') as f:#searching the text for strs
        s = f.read()
        for c in checkstr:
            groups = groupby(s.split(c))
            try:
                return [sum(1 for _ in group)+1 for label, group in groups if label==''][0]
            except IndexError:
                return 0



def readcsv(n):
    with open(f'{n}','r') as f:
        readed = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in readed:
            return row



def main():
    counter = 0
    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("Please start program with cmd arguments.")
        readtxt(argv[1], argv[2])#for fulling the checkstr
        for i in range(0,len(checkstr)): #Do this as much as the number of special strings
            for j in checkstr: #For each special string in the list
                if readtxt(argv[1], argv[2]) == readcsv(argv[1])[f'{checkstr[j]}']: #If dictionary value that returns for that spesific str is matches to the spesific str 
                    counter += 1
        if counter == len(checkstr): # if all spesific strs matches, then we found our person!
            print(readcsv(argv[1])['name'])
        #readtxt(argv[1], argv[2])
        #readcsv(argv[1])

main()
```

Comment: When executing the line `for i in range(0,len(checkstr)):` , **checkstr** is empty. This is a problem for sure

Comment: could you also provide an example of the command line execution command? Like `python myscript.py arg1 arg2...`

Comment: I added a `readtxt(argv[1], argv[2])` before the loop know `checkstr` should be loaded but still no outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer quite simple: you forgot an `else`-statement.

After you check the number arguments, you must place the `else`-statement.

```
def main():
    counter = 0
    if len(argv) != 3:
        print("Please use: program <csvfile> <textfile>")        # give usage and exit
    else:
        readtxt(argv[1], argv[2])#for fulling the checkstr
        for i in range(0,len(checkstr)): #Do this as much as the number of special strings
            for j in checkstr: #For each special string in the list
                if readtxt(argv[1], argv[2]) == readcsv(argv[1])[f'{checkstr[j]}']: #If dictionary value that returns for that spesific str is matches to the spesific str 
                    counter += 1
        if counter == len(checkstr): # if all spesific strs matches, then we found our person!
            print(readcsv(argv[1])['name'])
        #readtxt(argv[1], argv[2])
        #readcsv(argv[1])

main()
```